# How to transform this RN code into functional component with hooks?

Tags: react-native

I am working on the code below. How can I convert the class components into functional with hooks?

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/functional-vs-class-components-react-native/

Answer (score 1):

In this website you shared there is definition of both components functional and class so I can't explain I was just copied this class component

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    };
  }
  incrementCount () {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  }
  decrementCount () {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter - 1
    });
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
       <Text>Count: {this.state.counter}</Text>
        <Button onPress={this.decrementCount.bind(this)}>-</Button>
       <Button onPress={this.incrementCount.bind(this)}>+</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and now I am converting it to a functional component:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App () {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0) //<< replaced with this.state
   const incrementCount =()=> {
        setCounter(counter+1)
    }
   const decrementCount =()=> {
  
      setCounter(counter-1)
    }

      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Count: {counter}</Text>
          <Button onPress={decrementCount}>-</Button>
         <Button onPress={incrementCount}>+</Button>
        </View>
    );
 }
```